# Engineering a minimalist image interface without templates

Tags: c++, design-patterns, image, library

I'm practicing different ways of class design, so I'd like feedback on the design characteristics. Of course code practice comments are also welcome.

It was a conscious decision to omit templates. My next version will use a class template to store image data, similar to CImg and `boost::GIL`. I intend to make more classes with increasing complexity (templates, abstract base class, variadic templates). Until I reach a detailed yet highly abstract image class.

Header:

```
#ifndef AIMG
#define AIMG

#include <vector>
#include <string>

class AImg
{
public:
  const std::vector<short> dimsizes; //or std::array of length 4?
  const int N;     //# of elements ( = product of dimension sizes)
  unsigned int Bytes {1}; //bytes per element
  std::string tag; //meta info like "rgb"
  std::string cast;//used for returning data of type cast
  void* data;      //pointer to some array/container/byte-blob

  AImg(const std::vector<short>&); //you have to specify image size when creating. But may be empty of data.
  void setdata(void*);
  void* getdata();

  //example of pseudo-template method:
  void plusone(std::string);
  int operator()(unsigned int); //variable args would allow better indexing

private:
  int getN();
  //checkcast() ?
};

//public fcns
AImg::AImg(const std::vector<short>& input): dimsizes(input), N(getN()), cast("") {}
int AImg::operator()(unsigned int idx){
   if (cast=="int")
    {return ((int*)data)[idx];} else return 0;
  }
void  AImg::setdata(void* input){data=(void*)input;}
void* AImg::getdata(){return data;}
void  AImg::plusone(std::string cast){
        if (cast=="int")
        {
          int* idata = (int*)data;
          for (int i = 0;i<N;i++){idata[i] += 1;}
        }
        else if (cast == "float")
        {
          float* fdata = (float*)data;
          for (int i = 0;i<N;i++){fdata[i] += 1.0;}
        }
        //...other types
        // careful: N is based on elements of some user-defined type. Not all types have the same precision (#bytes).
        // So you'd need to normalize N based on the type size ( sizeof() ) to properly iterate over the data, or forbid certain types
      }

//Private fcns
int AImg::getN(){ //doesn't STL have a std::prod() ?!?!
  int prod = 1;
  for(short n : dimsizes) prod *= n;
  return prod;
}

#endif // AIMG
```

Main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "AImg.h"

using std::cout;  using std::cin;
using std::endl;  using std::vector;

int main()
{
  //create image object of size 2x2
AImg img(vector<short> {2,2});
  //create image data: simple int array
int d[4] {1,2,3,4};
img.setdata(d); //make sure length of d equals N, i.e. fill img up completely
img.plusone("int");
int* d2 = (int*)img.getdata(); //need to explicitly re-cast in c++
cout<<d2[0]<<d2[1]<<d2[2]<<d2[3]<<endl;
img.cast = "int";
cout<<img(0)<<img(1)<<img(2)<<img(3)<<endl;
}
```

Personally I think a class design like this is risky to use, so should I add more safety checks? It also seems harder to maintain and extend compared to a class using templates.

It also seems hard to extend the model to allow for inhomogenous (sub)pixels. For example, the value of a pixel at (1,1,1) could be an `int` but the value of the pixel at (1,1,2) could be an `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 6):

A few notes about things and stuff (I know, my introductions are always original):

- About that comment:

  ```
  //doesn't STL have a std::prod() ?!?!
  ```

  The standard library does have a function to compute the accumulated product of a range. It's called [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate). You can use it like this:

  ```
  int n = std::accumulate(
      std::begin(dimsizes), std::end(dimsizes),
      1, std::multiplies<int>{}
  );
  ```

  Agreed, it's a bit verbose. But the function is quite generic since it may work with any well-formed binary operation. Note that if you are using C++14, you can use `std::multiplies<>` instead of `std::multiplies<int>` and let the type be deduced.
- Also, you mentioned `std::array`. If you know for sure that you will only store 4 values and not more, then please, by all means, use an `std::array<short, 4>` instead of an `std::vector<short>`.
- Your case isn't really consistent. For local variables, the generally accepted practice is to use `snake_case` everywhere and to drop every capital letter.
- Ok, I hate to say this, but `void AImg::plusone(std::string cast)` without templates really hurts me. I know that you plan to change that later, but the current version still hurts me ç___ç Also, since you're not altering the `std::string`, it would be better to take a `const std::string&` parameter instead.
- Instead of that:

  ```
  int AImg::operator()(unsigned int idx);
  ```

  Array subcript tends to use the... well, the array subcript `operator[]` instead of the parenthesis. Unless you have to feed it several parameters, in which case `operator()` is sometimes preferred, but that's not your case.

  ```
  int AImg::operator[](unsigned int idx);
  ```
- I don't think that the method `setdata` really needs a cast from `void*` to `void*`:

  ```
  void AImg::setdata(void* input) { data = input; }
  ```

Comment: thanks! I felt the `operator[]` was more appropriate too, but I copied the CImg syntax which uses `operator()`. I also think the range product is way too verbose for such a fundamental operation. I checked if valarray had a method for it, but alas. The question of fixing the number of dimensions to 4 is one of design: Is using an array worth giving up modelling flexibility?

Comment: @jiggunjer I didn't quite understand what `dimsizes` was supposed to be actually. Can you have 3D or 4D images? If so, you could still make it a template parameter to have the flexibility but enforce things.

Comment: Yes, an image is modelled as a matrix (like MATLAB if you know it). @Morwenn Most images have 3 dimensions: x,y,color. But rather than making: `int width`,`int height`, etc as members I chose to store the sizes in a single array/vector member. So the width of an image is dimsizes[0], the height dimsizes[1], etc. I thought why limit the model dimensions, what if someone wants to add a time dimension (video)... etc

Comment: @jiggunjer `template<std::size_t Dims> class AImg { /* ... */ };` and then you can have the cake and eat it too (and also compute `N` at compile time).

Comment: I don't think a template for dimensions is needed. I can just call dimsizes.size() to get the number of dimensions. N is already computed at compile time I believe. The question is should I limit the user's options to create any M-dimensional cube or just 3 or 4 dimensions as is common in image processing?

Answer (score 4):

Generally looks pretty good to me.

I'd fix all of the indentation and formatting, especially in the header file.

```
AImg::AImg(const std::vector<short>& input): dimsizes(input), N(getN()), cast("") {}
int AImg::operator()(unsigned int idx){
   if (cast=="int")
    {return ((int*)data)[idx];} else return 0;
  }
void  AImg::setdata(void* input){data=(void*)input;}
void* AImg::getdata(){return data;}
```

Looks a bit nasty, in my opinion. Space isn't a premium, we can afford a few `\t` and `\n` characters in our code.

```
AImg::AImg(const std::vector<short>& input): dimsizes(input), N(getN()), cast("") 
{}

int AImg::operator()(unsigned int idx)
{
   if (cast=="int")
   {
       return ((int*)data)[idx];
   } else
   {
       return 0;
   }
}

void  AImg::setdata(void* input)
{
    data=(void*)input;
}

void* AImg::getdata()
{
    return data;
}
```

Looks a lot neater and more readable.

**Edit:**

Oop, noticed that you missed some braces in your `getN()` function after your `for` statement. Even if it is just a one line thing, put them in, it's not worth the headache of forgetting that it's not there.

Comment: cheers! I'm normally always pro braces with ifs and fors, but I skimped out since this was just a quick draft. Also this was my first post here so I was messing around with the formatting too much :p Will do better next time ;)

Comment: @jiggunjer Ctrl+k is a godsend. Copy paste your code as is, highlight it, then Ctrl k to indent the lot

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
```

Organize your includes.  On a small project like this, it's really easy to make sure you've included everything you want.  On a project that has 30+ includes from various sources (STL, Boost, LLVM, your own stuff, etc), it will be difficult to make sure you've included everything and there are no side-effects like cascading dependencies.  You should order your includes by reliability of source then name.

```
const std::vector<short> dimsizes; //or std::array of length 4?
```

`const std::vector` is fine since you are not templating but want to support varying dimensions.  I'd only use `std::array` if I were using templates.  As for the `short`, I'm a believer that if you are need a specific sized value, you should use the appropriate type from `<cstdint>` to maintain portability.

```
const int N;     //# of elements ( = product of dimension sizes)
unsigned int Bytes {1}; //bytes per element
```

If you have to use a comment to explain what a member is, you should rename that member.  Also, consider the actual type these variables will represent.  They are sizes and sizes are always positive.  Either go with `unsigned` or allow architecture flexibility (if needed) with `std::size_t`.

```
std::string tag; //meta info like "rgb"
std::string cast;//used for returning data of type cast
```

These feel like they should be enumerated values instead of `std::string`s.

```
void* data;      //pointer to some array/container/byte-blob
```

Is `AImg` responsible for the lifetime of data? Is it an adaptor that operates on some other set of data managed by something else?  Someone has to clean up data when the program exits.

```
void* getdata();
```

This function does not change the state of the object and should be qualified with `const` at the end.

As far as naming goes, avoid using the name `get` for your getters.  `get` implies a mutating or possibly destructive operation on the state of an object in a non-*by-value* world.  When you ***get*** cash from an ATM, you are taking cash out of the machine, leaving less in it.  Consider naming your getter `data()` and pre/suffix your member variables.

This seems like a good candidate to overload `operator*()`.

```
int operator()(unsigned int); //variable args would allow better indexing
```

I agree with @Morwenn regarding `operator()` vs `operator[]`.

```
AImg::AImg(const std::vector<short>& input): dimsizes(input), N(getN()), cast("") {}
```

`cast` is already default constructed to be empty.  No need to generate an empty c-string for it.

```
int AImg::operator()(unsigned int idx){
   if (cast=="int")
    {return ((int*)data)[idx];} else return 0;
}
```

That trailing `else` could potentially cause problems later.  Put each conditional branch on its own line to assist with readability and maintainability.

When interrupting flow control of a program using `return`, `break`, `continue`, do not use `else if` or `else` on that returning branch.  This helps reduce excessive indentations that may harm the readability of the non-branching path.

Comment: thanks. about the data management, could I use a shared/unique pointer to make the image object 'claim' the data? otherwise it is indeed like an adapter class for raw image data.

Comment: You definitely could use shared/unique_ptr.  I prefer unique_ptr and passing around observer/tidy_ptr (typesafe raw pointers) to reference the data.  When you get into ownership though, be aware of the rule of zero, rule of three, and rule of five.

Comment: Though I think in most cases just having a destructor call `delete [] data` is fine... assuming I can do that with a void*.

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like feedback on the design characteristics.

Alternative public declaration of the class, with comments on different aspects:

```
class AImg2
{
public:
    // const std::vector<short> dimsizes; //or std::array of length 4?
    // const int N;     //# of elements ( = product of dimension sizes)
    // unsigned int Bytes {1}; //bytes per element

    // better interface:

    // you say in a comment:
    // "So the width of an image is dimsizes[0], the height dimsizes[1], etc."
    using dim_sequence = std::array<unsigned short, 4>;
    enum class dimtype: int { width, height, /* etc */ };

    // public API instead of const public data
    const dim_sequence & dimensions() const;
    const unsigned_short operator[](dimtype type) const;

    // client code:
    // AImg2 img{ ... };
    // auto width = img[AImg2::dimtype::width];
    // const auto& dimensions = img.dimensions();

    // turned into a public API and
    // renamed from "tag" because you needed a comment:
    //     "std::string tag; //meta info like "rgb""
    std::string metadata_tag() const;

    // this is bad and you should feel bad:
    // void* data;      //pointer to some array/container/byte-blob
    // the data is public (bad)
    // it has no type information (void is doubly bad)
    // and it is a raw pointer (raw pointer is tripply bad)

    // better alternative:
    using byte_sequence = std::vector<unsigned char>;

    // pass by value and use std::move internally
    void bytes(byte_sequence bytes);

    // get data
    const byte_sequence& bytes() const;

    byte_sequence::value_type operator[](byte_sequence::size_type index) const;

    // this is a terrible idea:
    // void plusone(std::string);

    // because I can do this:
    // AImg2 img{ ... };
    // img.plusone("add one to each byte");

    // better alternative:
    enum class reinterpret_type { as_float, as_uint2, as_uint4 };
    void plusone(reinterpret_type type);
};
```

client code:

```
AImg2 img{ ... };
for(auto byte: img.bytes())
{
    // ...
}
```

You should probably also add a using directive with a local alias for `byte_sequence::value_type` and `byte_sequence::size_type`.

I only focused on the safety and ease of (mis)use of the public API. Will probably post some more on the code, later.